# Android: Stopwatch (Timer) in background Service

Tags: android, android-service

I want to make an android application that have punch in and punch out functionality. Scenario is when the user entered in an application it enters its task and press punch in button, When punch in button is press current date and time is saved in a local database and timer is running on background even i close an application but issue is it cannot run in background when i close an application and starts again timer starts from beginning.

How to figure out that my service is running and get that data?

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button startButton;
private Button pauseButton;

private TextView timerValue;

Intent intent;
long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
long updatedTime = 0L;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);

    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
            startService(intent);
            registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(MyService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
        }
    });

    pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);

    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
            stopService(intent);
        }
    });

}

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        updateUI(intent);
    }
};

private void updateUI(Intent intent) {
    int time = intent.getIntExtra("time", 0);

    Log.d("Hello", "Time " + time);

    int mins = time / 60;
    int secs = time % 60;
    timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs));
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
    startService(intent);
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(MyService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
}


}
```

MyService.java

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.widget.Toast;


 public class MyService extends Service
 {
private Intent intent;
public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.example.wajid.service";

private Handler handler = new Handler();
private long initial_time;
long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    initial_time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
    handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 1000); // 1 second

}

private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        DisplayLoggingInfo();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // 1 seconds
    }
};

private void DisplayLoggingInfo() {

    timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - initial_time;

    int timer = (int) timeInMilliseconds / 1000;
    intent.putExtra("time", timer);
    sendBroadcast(intent);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);

}



@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


}
```

Comment: i think poblem is with your broadcast receiver it goes out of memory right after activity destroyed define it globally and provide description in manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to run a timer? Instead, simply save the check-in time in shared preferences. On check-out, the two can be compared and the relevant time calculated.

If you are worried that the user might try to manipulate the local device clock, then instead of getting the local time, you can use network time.